# rails3 @ heroku: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/jquery.min"):

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

NOTE: SOLVED by changing `javascript_include_tag` from `:defaults` to `"application.js", "jquery.js", "rails.js"` which ar the ONLY 3 files anyway, but on Heroku for some reason it's trying to grab that extra jquery.min unless I do it this way.

---

(running locally we do not see this, just on Heroku)
Our Heroku logs show, after every GET request, another GET request to jquery.min which gives a routing error:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/jquery.min" for 1.2.3.4 at 2011-02-21 19:32:27 -0800
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/jquery.min"):
```

I can't figure out where that GET request is coming from.

Our layouts/application.html.haml says:

```
  %head
    %title
      = yield(:title) || "Untitled"
    %meta{"http-equiv"=>"Content-Type", :content=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}/
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag :defaults
    = csrf_meta_tag
    = yield(:head)
```

and the only 3 files in public/javascripts are application.js, jquery.js, and rails.js

FWIW our app is using JSON to communicate with a remote server.

But I cannot find any reference to "jquery.min" in our app (and for that matter, why doesn't the error message say jquery.min.js?)

Is jquery.min.js a file I *should* have? If so, where would I get that and install that?

I know in an earlier iteration of another app (we copied to start this app) a developer said something about using jquery.min to obfuscate some js code which we no longer have included).

---

One note: when looking at the page source of the page hosted at Heroku the mystery "jquery.min" (no js) is right there. FWIW it does not have the ?1298317536 after it)

```
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
<link href="/stylesheets/application.css?1298317536" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.min" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1298317536" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1298317536" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by changing `javascript_include_tag` from `:defaults` to `"application.js", "jquery.js", "rails.js"` which ar the ONLY 3 files anyway, but on Heroku for some reason it's trying to grab that extra `jquery.min` unless I do it this way.

Comment: It would probably be more appropriate to move the solution from your question to this answer post. Once this post contains your solution, you can accept your own answer to indicate that your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What are the js files listed in your config/application.rb file? Do you have something like this?

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery.min rails)
```

If yes, just remove the .min from the jquery, and everything should be fine.

EDIT: As long, of course, as you have jquery.js into your javascripts folder... :-)

EDIT2: Take a look at your /public/javascripts folder. What are the files in there?

Comment: good idea but no that line is comments out and doesnt have the .min anyway. the file sin my public/javascripts are the 3 file slisted in my question.